# scroll up is not working when open pdf in iframe or embed tag in react in windows machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, embed

`<embed src={cancellationPolicyUrl} type="application/pdf" height="450px" width="100%"></embed>`

or

```
<iframe src={cancellationPolicyUrl} height="450px" width="100%" />
```

where cancellationPolicyUrl is a PDF file URL that comes from the S3 server.

note: this code is used in the dialog box.

Comment: thanks, @KJ for replying, but when I open the dialog the PDF is working fine, which means open at the top, after that, I scroll down from the mouse and close the dialog and again open it at the same time then I want to open PDF from the top again but it opens from where I left that. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: thanks, @KJ for replying. So why it is working on other OS like Linux, I am facing this issue on the Windows machine.